# Redirecting to view with an id Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this page named Edition with url : `{{ url('edition/' . $edition->id) }}` and in that page there's a button to add data that goes to a form with this url `<a href="../journal/create?edition={{$edition->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add your journal to this edition</a>` .. My question is, how to redirect back to Edition page after I added new journal data to it ?

store method :

```
public function storejournal(JournalRequest $request) {
        $input = $request->all();

        //Input PDF
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $input['file'] = $this->uploadPDF($request);
        }

        //Insert data journal

        $id = $request->id; //request edition id

        $journal = Edition::findOrFail($id)->journal()->create($input);

        return redirect('//What should I add here ?//');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you want to use `return redirect()->back();` after storing data which will return user to a previous page.

If you want to return to some specified named route, you can do `return redirect()->route('route.name', $id);`

Or, you can just redirect to URL with `return redirect($url);`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects

Comment: This helped me, thank you! Guess I just need to read more about Laravel documentation haha